# Load a List type property from application yml into Java POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I want to load a nested List property into a JAVA POJO

I am loading the properties from yml using `ConfigurationProperties` annotation over a class A. My List is of type B. This B object has a LIST attribute of it's own. However yml properties are not getting loaded as expected.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="prop")
public class A{
List<B> b = new ArrayList<>(); 

//getters and setters ......
}

public class B{
String user; //This property gets loaded.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //However this list is still empty

//getters and setters ......
}
```

My properties in `application.yml` looks like below.

```
prop:
  -
  user: alpha
  list: a,b,c
  -
  user: beta
  list: x,y,z
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not the YAML syntax of a List:

`list: a,b,c`

That is just one string `a,b,c`.

If you wish to use a coma delimited list, you can parse it after you load it. 
Spring does something similar with some of its own properties, like in this example with RabbitMQ properties. The `addresses` are coma delimited, and the function `parseAddresses()` splits the string after loading, as part of the setter method of that member.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitProperties.java

Otherwise use the YAML list syntax.

```
prop:
  - user: alpha
    list: 
      - a
      - b
      - c
  - user: beta
    list:
      - x
      - y
      - z
```

Comment: Even after having it given that way, it doesn't work. It is not able to pick up the nested list and initialize it.

Comment: The syntax given by @jbx is correct for nested containers. You must have something wrong in your naming, nesting, or provision of accessors for the members.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) you define your list items as:

```
list: 
      - a
      - b
      - c
```